# SQL JOB AGENT (auto mail)

Tags: sql-server

My query is regarding SQL JOB AGENT (auto mail)I have created 2 queries in one procedure if from query one data is not coming then I don't want to send Email to given email list but it should send data from query two.

Comment: The short answer is to use some simple logic to test for the existence of rows - e.g., if exists (your query 1) then <send email using query 1> else <send email using query 2>

Comment: am storing query in varchar type variable. example- declare @body varchar(max), @body=(my query)  exec(@body) . so here if exists need Boolean type... right? how i will implement if exist??